# Fast filtering of a list by attribute of each element (of type scikit-image.RegionProperties)

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have a large (>200,000) list of objects (of type `RegionProperties`, produced by `skimage.measure.regionprops`). The attributes of each object can be accessed with `[]` or `.`. For example:

```
my_list = skimage.measure.regionprops(...)
my_list[0].area
```

gets the area.

I want to filter this list to extract elements which have `area > 300` to then act on them. I have tried:

```
# list comprehension
selection = [x for x in my_list if x.area > 300]
for foo in selection:
    ...

# filter (with predefined function rather than lambda, for speed)
def my_condition(x)
    return(x.area > 300)
selection = filter(my_condition, my_list)
for foo in selection:
    ...

# generator
def filter_by_area(x):
    for el in x:
        if el.area > 300: yield el
for foo in filter_by_area(prop):
    ...
```

I find that generator ~ filter > comprehension in terms of speed but only marginally (4.15s, 4.16s, 4.3s). I have to repeat such a filter thousands of times, resulting in hours of CPU time just filtering a list. This simple operation if currently the bottleneck of the whole image analysis process.

Is there another way of doing this? Possibly involving C, or some peculiarity of `RegionProperties` objects?
Or maybe a completely different algorithm? I thought about eroding the image to make small particles disappear and only keep large ones, but the measurements have to be done on the non-eroded image and finding the correspondance between the two is long too.

Thank you very much in advance for any pointer!

Comment: It sounds actually like the bottle-neck is whatever you're doing in the `for` loop, because in the case of the generator, your code won't be paying a time penalty to perform the entire filter up-front. Can you show some isolated code snippets that provide the profiler output of *just* the filtering part?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. Your remark helped me pin point the solution as I will provide in the answer below, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Mr. F, I tried isolating the filtering part by doing some dumb operation in the loop:

```
selection = [x for x in my_list if x.area > 300]
for foo in selection:
    a = 1 + 1
```

this resulted in exactly the same times as before, even though I was extracting a few properties of the particles in the loop before. This pushed me to look more into how the `area` property of particles, on which I am doing the filtering, is extracted.

It turns out that `skimage.measure.regionprops` just *prepares* the data to compute the properties, it does not compute them explicitly. Extracting one property (such as `area`) triggers the computation of all the properties needed to get to the extracted property. It turns out that the area is computed as the first moment of the particle image, which, in turns, triggers the computation of all the moments, which triggers other computations, etc. So just doing `x.area` is not just extracting a pre-computed value but actually computing plenty of stuff.

There is a simpler solution to compute the area. For the record, I do it this way

```
numpy.sum(x._label_image[x._slice] == x.label)
```

So my problem is actually very specific to scikit-image `RegionProperties` objects. By using the formula above to compute the area, instead of using `x.area`, I get the filtering time down from 4.3s to ~1s.

Thanks for Mr. F for the comment which prompted me to go on this exploration of the code of scikit-image and solve my performance problem (the whole image processing routine when from several days to several hours!).

PS: by the way, with this code, it seems list comprehension gets a (very small) edge over the other two methods. And it's clearer so that's perfect!